# AWS-RunBashScript errors/warnings with Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, celery, python-2.x, aws-ssm

I have many EC2 instances that retain [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) jobs for processing. To efficiently start the overall task of completing the queue, I have tested AWS-RunBashScript in AWS' [SSM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html) with a BASH script that calls a Python script. For example, for a single instance this begins with `sh start_celery.sh`.

When I run the command in SSM, this is the following output (compare to other output below, after reading on):

```
/home/ec2-user/dh2o-py/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/utils/imports.py:167: 
UserWarning: Cannot load celery.commands extension u'flower.command:FlowerCommand': 
ImportError('No module named compat',)
  namespace, class_name, exc))

/home/ec2-user/dh2o-py/tasks/task_harness.py:49: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without 
Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  task_configs = yaml.load(conf)

Running a worker with superuser privileges when the worker accepts messages serialized with pickle is a very bad idea!

If you really want to continue then you have to set the C_FORCE_ROOT
environment variable (but please think about this before you do).

User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0

failed to run commands: exit status 1
```

Note that only warnings are thrown. When I SSH to the **same** instance and run the **same** command (i.e. `sh start_celery.sh`), the following (same) output results *BUT* the process runs:

[image]

I have verified that the process does NOT run when doing this via SSM, and I have no idea why. As a work-around, I tried running the `sh start_celery.sh` command with bootstrapping in user data for each EC2, but that failed too.

So, why does SSM fail to actually run the process that I succeed in doing by actually via SSH to each instance running identical commands? The details below relate to machine and Python configuration:

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860). That's almost impossible to read (and for the visually impaired it _is_ impossible to read). Just copy and paste your text instead.

Comment: It would be the best if you made a systemd service out of Celery (described in the "Daemonization" section how to do so). Looks like when your run through SSM it runs the process as root (id=0) which is a "no no"... - It is always the best to make a dedicated user ("celery" for an example) that runs the service.